# How to install libuuid in MinGW/MSYS?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, cross-compiling, msys

I want to compile a Linux C++ application in MinGW/MSYS. However, when I use `./configure --host=i586-mingw32msvc`, it complains that **libuuid** is not available.

After googling for a long time, it seems that there is no such package in MinGW repository. So i have downloaded **uuid-dev** source package from Launchpad and try to build it in MinGW/MSYS. However, when i use `./configure --host=i586-mingw32msvc`, it complains that **ncurses or ncursesw** selected but library is not found.

It seems that there is no such package in MinGW. So i have downloaded **libncurses5.dev** package from Launchpad and try to build it in MinGW/MSYS. When i try to use `./configure --host=i586-mingw32msvc`, everything seems fine. But, when i run make, it shows a lot of error messages.

Since building **uuid-dev** is unsuccessful, i try to build **e2fsprogs** package in MinGW/MSYS. When i use `./configure --host=i586-mingw32msvc`, everything seems fine. However, when i try to run make, it shows a lot of error messages.

Appreciate if anyone can show me how to install **libuuid** in MinGW/MSYS. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use Cygwin instead of MinGW? Cygwin is intended for creating Linux applications on Windows.

Comment: Are you sure your MinGW install is good? Mine has `libuuid.a` inside `lib` out of the box.. If you aren't afraid of using a lib you downloaded from the net from some unknown guy (I _would_ be afraid to be honest, but still), I've uploaded it for you: [libuuid from MinGW-TDM-4.6.1](http://www.file-upload.net/download-3818312/libuuid.a.html).

Comment: Or... maybe you just need to tell `configure` something like `--with-libuuid=/path/to/mingw/lib`. Try `--help` to see if there's any such option. Sometimes it just doesn't find things that are there.

Comment: @Damon Thank you! After reading your comment, I searched the `/lib` folder in my MinGW. I found that my MinGW/MSYS also comes with libuuid.a. However, I don't know why `configure` still complains that libuuid is not available. I have also tried to use --<options>=</path> to point to the library files, but still no luck..

Comment: Try if there is something like a `--with-libuuid=path` switch. Usually `configure` has such a thing, which allows you to tell it to use exactly the library in the location you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following projects for implementations of libuuid

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/libuuid/
- http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/

But be careful: Windows/MinGW also has a libuuid.a that has nothing to do with this, so you must make sure you're linking with the one provided one of the libraries above and not the one from MinGW.